# Haarcascades don't work in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do some face detection here and using the standard cascades, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/), the following code should draw rectangles over eyes and the face, either the cascades aren't working at all or something's wrong with my code that's supposed to draw over the frame. Also would it be possible to grab the video feed and not have it inverted?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'A:\scripts\opencvstuff\haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'A:\scripts\opencvstuff\haarcascade_eye.xml')


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You need double backslashes for your path names - A:\\scripts\\opencvstuff\\haarcascade_eye.xml'

Comment: I thought the `r` was supposed to treat it as regex and would do the escaping. @GPPK

Comment: Ah right, could do. Worth a try though

Comment: I tried the double backslash it didn't work

Comment: @Sahil try `'A:/scripts/opencvstuff/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml'`

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't seem to work. I am downloading the whole OpenCV repo instead of manually downloading the Cascades that I need. Maybe I am not able to download it properly. @JeruLuke

Comment: @Sahil I learnt something new! Came across the usage of `r` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the code to work by changing the Face model from `haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml` to `haarcascade_frontalface_default`. Seems dumb but yeah that worked.

Comment: `haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml`: this will detect **cat**.!`haarcascade_frontalface_default`: this will detect human face!

Comment: I am laughing so hard right now, I didn't even see the word "cat" in between. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. I was gonna look at the XML file see what's up there to find what's the difference between the cascades.